# Performance in using xib file in ios

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch

I Have a `UIView` which contains 20 `UIImageView`  and every `UIImageView` updates its image 30 times in a second. I have created `UIView` and all `UIImageView` in xib file.

My doubts are as below.

1. Will there be any performance penalty in Using xib file?
2. should I create my `UIView` and `UIImageView` programmatically?

Comment: No, that should be fine.

Comment: Please Notice 20 UIImageView with 30 times update in a second....a slight difference could matter

Comment: Did you test this on a device?

Comment: it should be fine, but keep and watch the cpu activity.

Comment: The nib file is used use to load those views; it makes no difference at runtime.

Comment: Load it into Instruments and do some profiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xib file is basically another way of writing User Interfaces in **XML languages**. and Interface builder will write it for You when You were doing Drag and drop. Once parsing of xml file is being done there is **no difference** whether you wrote code to make User Interface or Used Interface builder.